# How do I create a taxonomy term blacklist?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have an "official" vocabulary and a "user-submitted" vocabulary. Content can be tagged from either list, and new user-created terms go into the user-submitted vocabulary.

Periodically, I will merge / rename the user-submitted tags to conform to a standard style, and then move them to the "official" vocabulary. This works well, *except* when users add a term that I later merge or remove - someone else is then free to add it again later.

So, how can I create a "blacklist" of terms that are disallowed for one or more vocabularies? Ideally, if a user tried to add the term as a free-tag, they would get an error when the form is submitted.

I'm using the following modules, if it makes a difference:

- Taxonomy
- Content Taxonomy
- Taxonomy Formatter
- Taxonomy Manager

Comment: Would https://drupal.org/project/term_permissions work for you?  If you deny access to "blacklisted" terms, this may achieve the requested feature. [disclaimer: I don't know that module and never tried it, just a suggestion/idea/quick comment].

Comment: @GaëtanFrenoy It might work, yes, but I'd need a stable 7.x release since this is a production site, and it doesn't look like that's going to happen for a little while.